# Gradients not smooth

Tags: html, css, frontend, gradient

I tried making a gradient with a lot of colors but the gradient doesn't comes up smooth as it should be here's the screenshot  ...[messed up gradient](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kI2sv.jpg)

Comment: It looks as though you haven't got background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat and background-size: cover but without seeing your CSS and the related HTML it's impossible to tell exactly what you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

try setting the background-size: cover;
background- repeat: no repeat;

It also depends on the div or element you're trying to style. need more info n to add your code

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this method the most to create a gradient:

```
background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #a1a1a1, #2200ff);
```

It could also help to set `background-repeat: none;` or `background-size: cover;`.